# How can I change the color of weekdays header from Date picker calendar?

Tags: html, css, angular, datepicker

I am planning to change the default blue color of the weekdays header for accessibility (refer highlighted area of screenshot). I have tried using the below code in the CSS file, but whatever color code I change, I am not able to see the changes in the UI. Not sure what am I missing. Can you please throw some light?

```
.ngb-dp-weekday {
  color: #303536;
}
```

[image: Calendar]

[image: DOM]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't have access to the `color: var(--info)` css, otherwise you'd just go change it there.

To override the other css you need to increase specificity. You can do this by repeating the class name as many times as necessary.

```css
.ngb-dp-weekday.ngb-dp-weekday {
  color: #303536;
}
```

```css
.ngb-dp-weekday.ngb-dp-weekday.ngb-dp-weekday {
  color: #303536;
}
```

until it works.

Comment: I have tried the above and still it does not work

Comment: Hmm, I actually noticed the color you show crossed out in the inspector is not the same as the one in your css. Does that line even correspond to your css? Are you sure you haven't put this css in a separate component with view encapsulation enabled?

Comment: I am not sure about the crossed out color. but other one I can change manually. Wondering if I am depicting the class details incorrectly, but unable to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Where have you put the css you showed? Is it in a component style file or in a global style file? If it's in a component, have you disabled view encapsulation? What do you mean you can change one 'manually'?

Answer (score 0):

ngb-bootstrap usually use ViewEncapsulation.None, so you need put your .css in a style general, not in style of the component

You can try write in your **styles.css** some like

```
  ngb-datepicker .ngb-dp-weekday{
    color:red;
  }
```

If not work enclosed your input in a div with class="custom"

```
<div class="custom">
...your ngbDatepicker..
</div>
```

and use

```
  .custom ngb-datepicker .ngb-dp-weekday{
    color:red;
  }
```

if only want one special datepicker, Since ngb-bootstrap 9, you has the property `datepickerClass` so you can write some like

```
<input ngbDatepicker [datepickerClass]="'custom'" ...>
```

And in styles.css you write

```
  ngb-datepicker.custom .ngb-dp-weekday{
    color:pink;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ::ng-deep

```
:host ::ng-deep .ngb-dp-weekday {
  color: #303536;
}
```